Clone/Copy repo from AzureDevOps to Databricks
I need to create or copy the repo from Azure DevOps to Azure Databricks using a service principal (Service Connection) without the need to ask for the secret value since im not allow (security purposes)
Currently im not using python whl, or databricks bundle so the documentation provided by Microsoft doesnt help that much.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-azure-devops
I have the CI that wraps all the files in artifact (.zip), all i need is to clone or copy that in /Repos in databricks in the name of the service principal, which im not getting.
Any idea?
I did try the documentation from Microsoft, and Databricks but i dont need the workspace copy, i need to copy on the Repos only

You can use the Databricks CLI in Azure DevOps pipeline to clone the repo to Databricks.
Steps:

Create a personal access token in azure devops with code read permission.  We will use it to provide git credentials in the pipeline.


Create a pipeline with the following yaml file. The first Azure CLI task is used to save the service principal from the service connection and then we can use it in the second task.


trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'service connection name'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;]$servicePrincipalKey" 
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID;]$servicePrincipalId" 
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID;]$tenantId"
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
- script: |
      curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/databricks/setup-cli/main/install.sh | sh
      databricks git-credentials create AzureDevOpsServices --git-username yourname  --personal-access-token $(pat) 
      databricks repos create "https://orgname@dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_git/reponame"
  env:
      DATABRICKS_HOST: $(DATABRICKS_HOST)
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(ARM_CLIENT_ID)
      ARM_TENANT_ID: $(ARM_TENANT_ID)
  displayName: 'install databricks cli and Run databricks  repos create'



Create the variables  DATABRICKS_HOST and pat.
DATABRICKS_HOST is your URL https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.azuredatabricks.net/.
pat is the personal access token you created in step 1.


Copy the repo URL from Azure DevOps and replace the one in the yaml.




Add your managed identity to your Azure Databricks workspace.


You can go to the service connection page and click the Manage Service Principal to go to the Manage Service Principal page.



copy the  Display name and Application (client) ID



In your Azure Databricks workspace, click your username in the top bar and click Settings. Click Identity and access and manage Service principals.

Add Service principal, choose Microsoft Entra ID managed, fill in the  Display name and Application (client) ID you copied and add.



Run the pipeline and the repo is cloned from Azure DevOps to Azure Databricks.


The owner of the repo is the  service principal.




Yes, but the owner of the repo its associated with the account that configurates the repo on databricks, i need the service principal to be the owner

Hi @Apuntatis, I have updated the answer to make the service principal is the owner of the repo.  Please check, thanks!

Hi @Apuntatis, may I know if the answer can help solve your question? Please let me know if you have questions about the steps in my answer.
